# Rest Api manipulating URL to get X amount of results

Tags: rest, url, curl, prestashop

how to force api to get specified amount of results ?
Now I use:

```
api/orders/?display=full&filter[date_add]=[2016-04-23,2018-06-23]&date=1
```

And I got all the results from this date filter but i want to trim amount of results to 5 for example. Is there any method to set maximum amount of resluts ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve pagination? You can send the number of results you want and the number you need to skip with the parameters in Rest Api call. The trimming is generally done at the db level i.e. you can send the number of results required  in the fetch query of your db.

Comment: For better performance i need to fetch specified amount. Now i can get all the results but it is to big for one request so i need to divide it into few requests.

Comment: Yes that is what pagination is for . If it is a list that you need to fetch then  you can send in  two parameters that is skip and limit. Initially the skip will be 0 and limit will be 5 then in the next request the skip will be 5 with limit unchanged. You can pass on this data to your fetch query as I mentioned before. Which DB are you using?

Comment: Currently it is not realated with db at all. I call api then fetch data and serialize it into objects. Pagination - i will remember :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, i need to set limit which looks like:

```
api/orders/?display=full&filter[date_add]=[2016-04-23,2018-06-23]&date=1&limit=1
```